# Cannot ping or be pinged by any other devices on network

Tags: networking, wireless, server, internet

I have just completed a fresh install of Ubuntu Server on an old PC. The PC is being connected to my local network via Wi-Fi. The Wi-Fi card is a TP-Link TL-WN751ND.

The server connects to the network fine and has Internet access. The issue is that it cannot successfully ping my desktop system and the desktop system cannot ping the server. The server *can* ping all of the other devices on my network, which, in turn, can ping the server too.

I'm at a loss as to why the Ubuntu PC and my (Windows 10) desktop cannot communicate but everything else can. My network card in the desktop is based on an Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260. The router is a BT HomeHub4 and all systems use DHCP but the router is set to assign each device a static IP. Both systems correctly receive their allocated IPs.

Desktop: 192.168.1.69
Server: 192.168.1.70
Gateway: 192.168.1.254
Subnet: 255.255.255.0

It's probably worth mentioning that the issue persists when using the Ubuntu Desktop 15.04 install I have on the same PC but I'm not sure if this is being caused by a Windows - Linux issue (unlikely, other machines communicate with server fine as mentioned) or something wrong with one of the network cards preventing the two communicating.

Any advice appreciated,
Ilmiont

On server (192.168.1.70): `ip route get 192.168.1.69`

```
192.168.1.69 dev wlan0  src 192.168.1.70
    cache
```

tracert (Desktop)

```
Tracing route to HPPavilionSlim-UbuntuServer.home [192.168.1.70]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

 1  IlmiontDesktop.home [192.168.1.69]  reports: Destination host unreachable.

 Trace complete.
```

Comment: Start the command `ip route get 192.168.1.70` on your **Desktop** and  `ip route get 192.168.1.69` on your **Server**. [edit] your question and add the output of both commands.

Comment: Edited. Used tracert as comparable Windows command for the desktop.

Comment: Your gateway is 192.168.1.254, right? Add the output of `ping -c3 192.168.1.254` on 192.168.1.70

Comment: Not sure, I'm no expert, but do you have the firewall enabled on the client machine? `ufw` is its name on Ubuntu. You can check with `sudo ufw status`.

Comment: on 192.168.1.70 start `ip route add default via 192.168.1.254` and give me the output of `ip route`

Comment: sudo ufw status: "Status: inactive". Output from ping -c3 192.168.1.254 is all fine, 0% packet loss.

Comment: Sorry, you have a router in your network?

Comment: And the IP of the router is 192.168.1.254?

Comment: I have a router and yes it is 192.168.1.254. Adding a route returns "RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted." With sudo, it is "RTNETLINK answers: File exists". ip route returns "default via 192.168.1.254 dev wlan0 (newline) 192.168.1.0/24 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.70"

Comment: Can your desktop ping the router?

Comment: Yes, all devices can ping the router. The server can ping the router. It is just this connection between PC wireless and server wireless. Ping won't work either way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29372/discussion-between-a-b-and-ilmiont).

Answer (score 1):

**Symptom:** The only device you can access or ping are your device and the router

**My Solution** (Which worked for me when I had wasted 3 days trying to fix this issue): Just reset your modem. Its having the problem.

1. Reset your modem to factory defaults.
2. Reload the configuration of the modem
3. Test if the problem is solved

I had an option to downgrade the software version using a software reload option in my Optilink modem. I used that as well. But I am not sure if it would be necessary.